# pandas: How to remove strings from columns in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the following format. I want to remove strings that are appearing in `'TIMES_Sold'` column and replace it with 0 and then convert the column to integers.

Similarly, remove 'each' from the `'ITEM_Price_£'` column and convert it to float. How can I be able to do that?

```
TIMES_Sold  ITEM_Price_£
13            14.99
0             6.95 each
0             10.95 each
56            8.75
0             8.50 each
979           3.25
0             20.08
4             8.82
 Portable Gas Sniffer         9
2             15.46
```

Output should look like this:

```
TIMES_Sold  ITEM_Price_£
13            14.99
0             6.95 
0             10.95
56            8.75
0             8.50
979           3.25
0             20.08
4             8.82
0             9
2             15.46
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one way to do it

```
df['TIMES_Sold'] = df['TIMES_Sold'].str.strip().replace(r'\D\s','0', regex=True).astype(int)
df['ITEM_Price_£'] = df['ITEM_Price_£'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([0-9\.\,]*)')
df
```

```
    TIMES_Sold  ITEM_Price_£
0        13      14.99
1        0        6.95
2        0       10.95
3        56       8.75
4        0        8.50
5        979      3.25
6        0       20.08
7        4        8.82
8        0        9
9        2       15.46
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not giving the output as yours. In my case its returning the same string in a column.

Comment: Also, its adding a 0 after each interger for example for 13 its giving 130.

Comment: Thanks again. now, its not adding a 0 but also, not removing [' Portable Gas Sniffer']. maybe because there is a white space before the word portable??

Comment: there is a white space before (portable) in ( Portable Gas Sniffer)

Comment: yes I have added strip.

Comment: its giving error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,211'

Comment: Giving the same error again: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,211'

Comment: Can you share the data for which you receive error? The solution worked for the provided data sample. Secondly, are you converting the price to int?

Comment: yes, I am converting the price to int.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[["TIMES_Sold", "ITEM_Price_£"]] = df[["TIMES_Sold", "ITEM_Price_£"]].astype(str).apply(lambda col: pd.to_numeric(col.str.replace(r"[^\d\.]+", "0", regex=True)))

df.TIMES_Sold = df.TIMES_Sold.astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are multiple columns in my dateset, I just want to remove string from these columns that I showed in question.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: thanks again, its not replacing (' Portable Gas Sniffer to Locate Gas Leaks') with 0 in the column ['TIMES_sold'].

Comment: @MuhammadHusnainAliNasir it works for me, can you give `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: @S.B thanks, if it worked for OP, I add explanation

Comment: { 'TIMES_Sold': {0: '6 ', 1: '0', 2: '8 ', 3: '5 ', 4: '3 ', 5: '13 ', 6: '0', 7: '0', 8: '56 ', 9: '0'}, 'ITEM_Price_£': {0: '7.32', 1: '38.02', 2: '20.37', 3: '28.83', 4: '10.35', 5: '14.99', 6: '6.95 each', 7: '10.95 each', 8: '8.75', 9: '5.95 each'},}

Comment: Its only for 10 rows the data I want to remove is in 3000+ row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.replace` with the following regex patterns

```
df['TIMES_Sold'] = df['TIMES_Sold'].str.replace('\D', '0', regex=True).astype(int)
df['ITEM_Price_£'] = df['ITEM_Price_£'].str.replace('[^\d.]+', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Output

```
>>> df

   TIMES_Sold  ITEM_Price_£
0          13         14.99
1           0          6.95
2           0         10.95
3          56          8.75
4           0          8.50
5         979          3.25
6           0         20.08
7           4          8.82
8           0          9.00
9           2         15.46
```

- `\D` -  Matches anything other than a digit;
- `[^\d.]+`- Matches anything other than a digit or the literal `.` as many times as possible (although the `+` is optional in this case)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Its giving the correct output for ['ITEM_Price_£'] column. But, adding zero to a integers in ['TIMES_Sold'] column also, its not removing the strings in this column.

Comment: there is a white space before (portable) in ( Portable Gas Sniffer)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Good luck. BTW, your output is integer wheareas it says float in your question.

```
import string
alphabets=[string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase]
#print(alphabets)
df["TIMES_Sold"]=(df["TIMES_Sold"].where(~df["TIMES_Sold"].str.contains('[alphabets]'),'0')).astype(float)
df
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but, its giving the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,211 '

Comment: Are there special characters such as %$#@ and so on in TIMES_Sold? If so, you have to include them in the 'contains'. It works absolutely fine for me given the dataset you provided here.

Comment: Your data contains punctuations. I assume it as well contains special characters.

Comment: I have double checked the data it does not contain any special character or punc.

Comment: there is a punctuation to this entry: 1,211.